# Why doesn't translate work on some characters?

Tags: oracle, varchar2

I am trying to remove certain characters from a `VARCHAR2` using translate. Characters `160` (some kind of space) and `243` (paragraph control character?), however, appear to be "phantom" characters that are undetectable by both `INSTR` and `TRANSLATE`.  `LENGTH` works, but only if it's the only character in a string.  `LENGTH(CHR(160))` returns `1`, but `LENGTH(CHR(160) || CHR(110))` also returns `1` when you'd think it would return `2`. I've found that `REPLACE` works in stripping these phantom characters from a string, but I like translate better because it's easier to read and maintain whereas a long nesting or `REPLACE` functions is just cumbersome.

Is there some other way to strip these characters from a `VARCHAR2` without using replace?

EDIT:  It appears that character 243 elsewhere registers as `≤`.  However, Oracle has no problem displaying this character when I selected it explicitly.  When I select `CHR(243)`, it just displays the block replacement character.  Plus, [this source](http://www.oralytics.com/2012/11/ascii-to-character-conversion-in-oracle.html) points 243 to the paragraph character which makes more sense since that's a control code.

Comment: `ASCIISTR()` could strip out them..

Comment: @OracleUser This is actually getting closer.  However, it doesn't strip unsupported characters, but instead converts them to `\FFFD\FFFD`.  If it can convert them, it stands to reason that it could also remove them.  I can't use a regex in case `\FFFD` is ever a valid string in the column.

Comment: Can you give me `dump(your_column)` for a sample ?

Comment: Here's an example:
select dump('沈阳市' || chr(160) || chr(243) || chr(15712189) || chr(15556979) || chr(15300713)) from dual;
I need to also support Kanji characters, so I don't know if ASCIISTR will work.

Comment: select length(chr(160)||chr(110)) from dual;  Returns 2 in my database.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a regular expression?  This removes your trouble characters by replacing char 160 or 243 with nothing:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('abc' || chr(160) || chr(243) || 'def', '(' || chr(160) || '|' || chr(243) || ')', '') from dual;

REGEXP
------
abcdef

SQL>
```